# php dynamic drop down menue picking values from data-base

Tags: php

i am using following code to insert data into mysql database

```
<?php
$refselect  = $_POST['refselect'];
$refname    = $_POST['refname'];
$refemail   = $_POST['refemail'];
$refcnt     = $_POST['refcnt'];
$refdes     = $_POST['refdes'];
$referror   = $cberror = "<h1>Data not Added</h1><br/><br/><h3>Please Follow The Instructions</h3>";
$urefdb     = "INSERT INTO refdb(reftype,refname,refemail,refcnt,refdes) VALUES ('$refselect','$refname','$refemail','$refcnt','$refdes');"; 

include_once("db.php");

if ($refselect == "Select Type") die ("$referror");

if (empty ($refname)) die ("$referror");

if (mysql_query("$urefdb"))

{
echo "<h3>One Record Updated Successfully with the following Details </h3><br/>";
echo "Reference Type =$refselect <br/><br/>";
echo "Reference Name = $refname <br/><br/>";
echo "Reference E-Mail = $refemail <br/><br/>";
echo "Reference Description = $refdes <br/><br/>";

}
else
{
echo mysql_error();
}

?>
```

"refselect" data is coming from a drop down menu at the page now i want that as i add data through this form another form located at another page pic "refname" from database as i update "refdb" that drop down menu pick data accordingly

what to do now ?

Comment: (not an answer to your question, but still useful) You should really escape the data you are getting from the user, before injecting it into an SQL query (you can read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection and see http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string )

Comment: this matter i will consider later thanks for comments.

Comment: Also there is no reason to put variables in quotes if they are the only content of a string. For example, you can change "$referror" to just $referror.

Answer (score 0):

To update the values of another form by changing a select's value, you need to learn about javascript's "onchange" event.